# Why isn't reputation passed between Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, stackexchange

I don't understand it, why do we have to make our reputation separately on Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User even if the accounts are linked?

Comment: becuase programmers do not necessarily make good sysadmins, and super users do not necessarily make good programmers, and visa versa. My rep is higer on SU than SF as I am more knowledgeable about using computers rather than administering. I could have a combined rep of 500 from SU and SF but on SO it would mean nothing.

Comment: This might even be a question for StackOverflow Meta, since usually questions relating to the entire trilogy belong there. I don't see any way to move it there though.

Comment: shocking that somebody could ask such a question

Answer (score 19):

Imagine this:

You're a professional baseball player and are considered the very best in the world, now would that also automatically make you a good chess player, a proper teacher or a physicist?

The same goes for the SE quartet, your expertise on one of the four subjects doesn't necessarily make you an expert on the other three subjects. Therefore, reputation or "trust by the community" on each subject should be earned separately.

Even though it's not always just, deep down inside you will probably trust a 10k rep user over a 1 rep user.

Imagine this (unreal) example: an incredible programmer from Stack Overflow who knows nothing about viruses recommends to never install virus protection because it will slow down his development kit... He has 50k rep on SO and therefore will also have 50k on SU... would you want a 50k rep user to give answers like that on SU?

Comment: Or a basketball super star turned baseball player *cough* Michael Jordan *cough* it just doesn't always work.

Comment: Hmm, but is there any reason not to share rights achieved on one site between all StackOverflow sites? You don't need to be an expert to fix formating, determine off-topic questions, etc...

Comment: @Let_Me_Be as long as we're still getting comments from other SE's mods about migrating wrong questions and double migratios still occur, I will not consider anyone capable of determining off topic questions. Rep is not just about answering questions right, but also about experience with that SE site.

Comment: +1 nice post! really good analogy. :-)