# It’s annoying and hypocritical that reputation is split between StackExchange sites.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why reputation is not passed between superuser, stackoverflow and serverfault?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1532/why-reputation-is-not-passed-between-superuser-stackoverflow-and-serverfault)

Why am I not permitted to downvote, comment, or use community wikis here on SU (yet) when over on Stack Overflow, I am?

For a network that loves single sign-on solutions like OpenID, doesn’t this seem rather **inconsistent**?

It’s not like SU can’t trust that my reputation on SO is genuine, you know? And it’s not like they are wholly separate entities — the little StackExchange widget at the top left shows me notifications from across the network!

Comment: You get a +100 rep bonus if your SO account is over 200+. If that has not happend un and then re associate your accounts

Comment: it does indeed look like your accounts aren't linked. Link your accounts from the prefs menu, and you'll automatically get +100 rep for associating your super user and stack overflow accounts if you have at least 200 rep on SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just because you may be a programming genius doesn't ALWAYS make you a Super User, Gaming, Cooking or any of the other Stack Exchange sites expert.  In order to have the privileges that you have on Stack Overflow you have to earn them here, just as any other user would have to on any SE site.  If you really do know you stuff, which I'm going to assume that you do, then it won't take long really to get the same privileges.

If it's any help as well, you automatically receive 100 rep for linking the two accounts.  This means that you do not have the limitations of a new user.  You are respectfully appreciated for your hard work, while still forcing you to earn the higher privileges.

Comment: Well Said @KronoS

Comment: True, but coming to a new SE site and not having the abilty to comment on posts (like this), flag spam posts or simply upvote and answer that fixed my issue is *really* irritating.  (I only have enough rep to post this comment due to @Benny's comment abourt re-linking accounts.)

Comment: @grhm - that's an argument that some of the numbers & priviledge levels might need *tweaking*, not necessarily one that all the numbers need merging. The rep is often used as a guide to someone's level of knowledge/trustworthiness, and just because I'm "worth" 8k of trust on ServerFault doesn't mean that my comments on SU about home computer setups are "worth" 8k, and it might result in a bad experience to a visitor if they followed such overinflated advice.

Comment: @Robert Moir - I agree, and re-reading my comment I don't think I made that clear.  If a user has proven a trustworthly member of one SE site - they should be deemed to understand the ethos a SE site and thus be allowed some of the basic privileges.  I suspect this is what the +100 bonus for linking account is meant to achieve.