# How about sharing reputation across merged accounts?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't reputation passed between Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1532/why-isnt-reputation-passed-between-stack-exchange-sites)

I have cross-linked accounts on several stack exchange sites (Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Super User, Ask Ubuntu), but unfortunately the reputations are tracked independently.  Couldn't they be merged?  That is, one reputation score for all account avatars?

Comment: That's a feature, not a bug

Answer (score 3):

No, that wouldnt be a good idea because your skills in one field do not reflect your skills in others

Example: I could be a moderately skilled person where topics from superuser are concerned

Does not in any way mean that I have any skills in Ubuntu or say anything about my English skills

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered somewhere. (edit ... [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1532/why-isnt-reputation-passed-between-stack-exchange-sites))

I believe the argument is that just because you are an expert on computers, it doesn't make you an expert of cookery. Having your computer reputation show up on cookery might give people there a misleading impression of your expertise and reliability as a source of cookery advice.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you wouldn't want to trust **me** with cooking for someone else :P